# How to delete non existing external disk

Tags: disk, fdisk

Long time ago i was trying to fix a corrupted sd card, or usb, i don't remember.
After some failed attemps, i give up, but the disk keeps showing up with fdisk -l, gparted, and disks.
How can i delete this ghost disk?

This is the ghost disk:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 22,4 GiB, 24015495168 bytes, 46905264 sectors
Disk model: SanDisk SSD U100
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: BC49F78D-AD2F-4BEA-8731-80F808B9120D
```

Comment: please show `sudo  lsblk -f` edit your question for output.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the second option at the end, i had to do this with the same issue after fdisk did not delete it.

"Other option is to check fstab and see if there is an entry for it, if so remove it"

Re-adding fsdisk steps in case someone else may find it useful

First, get a listing of your current partition scheme, type the following command:
fdisk -l

You Listed you want to remove a partition from /dev/sdb disk. Type the following command:
fdisk /dev/sdb

Now type p command to list partition:
Command (m for help): p

If you see partitions, remove them just to be safe /dev/sdb3 (3rd partition). Type the d command to delete a partition:

Command (m for help): d

Partition number (1-4): 3

It will prompt you for the partition number. Type 3:

Verify that partition deleted:

Command (m for help): p

Now save the changes and exit to shell prompt. Type the w command:
Command (m for help): w

Reboot the system.